# How to get post data from html form in nodes with express4?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my main.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var userAPI = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

userAPI.post('/mydir/hello', function(req, res){
  console.log("hi");
  console.log(req.body.name);
  console.log(req.body.country);
  res.send('Name: ' + req.body.name);
  res.send('Name: ' + req.body.country);
  res.end();
});

app.use('/', userAPI);
app.listen(12345);
```

and here is my test_post_method.html form

```
<form action="/mydir/hello" method=""POST">
    name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
    country: <input type="text" name="country"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When I go to http://localhost:12345/test_post_method.html, I can see the form and input "test for name" and "1234 for country for country" to test.

Then I click submit and only got this message

```
Cannot GET /mydir/hello?name=test&country=1234
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: extra " for method=""POST"

Comment: Thanks. I am so stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML forms do not send JSON.

You need `bodyParser.urlencoded()`.

You also need to tell the HTML to send a POST, without a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks.Now works. I remove extra " and also use bodyParse.urlencoded().But why I got "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." in my console?

Comment: See the docs `send()`; you can only call that once.  http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send

Comment: Thank you so much.I am new to express and sorry for ask stupid question :)